# how to apply css files in servlet code written inside jsp file?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, servlets

Below is my code. I have all css files in webcontent root and inside css folder.

```
String cssLocation = request.getContextPath() + "/WebContent/css/style.css";
String cssTag = "<link rel='stylesheet'<img class=gallery_img'> type='text/css' href=' "+ cssLocation +" '>";
out.println("<h4> <p><div class='gallery_img'> " + rs.getString("title") + "</div></div></P></h4>");
out.println("");
out.println("<a href='#'><div style='float:left;width:10% border:10px solid;padding:20px ;'><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'><table style='width:50%' ><td><img width='230' height='230' src=displayphoto?id=" +  rs.getString("id") + "  style='opacity: 1'></img></td></table></body></a> <p/>");
```

Comment: This is very bad practice.. You should not mix-up the code from the representation layer with the code of the back-end. The next guy will touch this will be extremely unhappy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please send me some links regarding my query

Answer (score 0):

All jsp files are converted into servlet java files and compiled, you can simply call this jsp file and go get the servlet file from the cache directory. copy the css part and paste into your own servlet,you can even make it a function or a seperate class.

If you can't find the servlet cache directory simply search the name of the jsp file without extension on the hard drive, you will see that there is a java file with that name. 
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply..please share some working piece of code.